# FastAPI hosting issue on IIS

Tags: python, iis

I am trying to host simple FastAPI application on IIS.

When i am trying to host flask Application then its working but with FastAPI its throwing below error

Error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aimeqcuser1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 847, in main
    result = handler(record.params, response.start)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
```

StdOut:

StdErr:

Comment: The error message shows that the call need a parameter. So did you pass a paramter? You'd better show more error code and web.config message.

Comment: Actually I am getting this error while hosting the application in IIS. if I run the program locally then it's running fine